# YUI DataTable Changing DraggableColumn and Resizable

Tags: datatable, yui

After a YUI2 datatable is constructed, is it possible to change configuration settings dynamically?

If draggableColumns was not set true when the datatable was initialized, how can I change that behavior later on?
Similarly, when columns are not identifed as resizable, is there a way to change it later?

I expected a datatable method would allow this to happen (set on/off), but I can't seem to find something like that in the API (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/module_datatable.html).

So, I tried browsing the datatable object and changing each column's 'draggable' flag.  That didn't work and it also didn't seem the right way to do it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every element's configuration object can be accessed via it's `cfg` attribute.

So, in order to set `draggableColumns` config property dynamically, you need to use :

```
myDatatable.cfg.setProperty("draggableColumns", "true", true)
```

Note that the second boolean argument should be a string. Refer this [link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Config.html#method_setProperty) for reference.